# Launch file error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After entering a command "projectbot_world.launch, I see problems like:

```
Invalid <arg> tag: projectbot_gazebo
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share. 

Arg xml is <arg name="world_name" value="$(find projectbot_gazebo)/worlds/projectbot.world"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Thanks a lot :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341104/launch-file-error/) by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here is that you haven't sourced your workspace so the package `projectbot_gazebo` isn't found. The two `ROS path` lines that you get from the error are all the data within the variable `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, when using `$(find PKG)` you will search if a package can be found at the different pathes of the variable.
Sourcing your catkin workspace add the path of the packages of your workspace to this variable.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-06**:
I'm not sure this is the case. We'd typically see a "ResourceNotFound" error in that case.

The OP here posts a "Invalid  tag".

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-06**:
I've tried different errors by trying to find something that doesn't exist :

- Within an `arg` tag as OP's error and it returned the same error.
- Within a `node` tag the output error is the different pathes of `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
- Within an `include` tag indeed I got the error `ResourceNotFound`

I would guess that when using the `include` tag an error is raised before the error when parsing the xml file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-06**:
Interesting. Thanks for checking.

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2020-01-10**:
So what Exactly should I do? I don't understand the sollution :(

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-10**:
You have to source your workspace.